# Backtrack 4 as a primary development OS

Tags: operating-systems, backtrack

I want to use Backtrack 4 as my primary OS on a netbook. However since I'm an app developer, I need tools such as MonoDevelop, Git, VM, etc. etc. I know that I can install everything I need on an Ubuntu 10.04 OS.

Do you think I'll encounter any problems when I make the switch?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to Compile Software from the Source then you will not have any problems.

But are you sure that you want to use BackTrack as a Primary OS? the distro is made for penetration testing so you'll find Lots and Lots of software that you might not need.

I Would Suggest to keep Ubuntu as a primary OS and Just add the tools that you find useful in BackTrack to Ubuntu, that would be easier plus that you will find almost everything compiled and ready in the ubuntu repositories while BackTrack repositores are still small compared to Ubuntu's.

Comment: I know this thread is old but doesn't BT4 use Ubuntu so can't it access Ubuntu's repo as well?

Answer (score 1):

eslambasha has a point on it being a single purpose OS, but if you are trying to develop packages for backtrack I could see a point.  There's also some package mangling that goes on in BT to get some of the older tools to work(unless they removed them in R2).

All that being said, I dual boot ubuntu 10.10 and bt4 with a data partition I mount at /media/persistent or wherever